# summing the number to the specified value

Tags: c++

We consider a following situation:
Suppose you have a single integer k and n integers. Now we need to write a function that for such data will determine if we can get the number of k as the sum of a subset of numbers. It must operate in a recursive way.
For example input:

```
IN:
k: 12
14 25 36 8 78 15 26 
OUT:
NO
k: 118
14 25 36 8 78 15 26 1 2 7
YES, 78+14+26
```

Comment: -1 what is the question? (anyway, google up partitioning)

Comment: What you have stumbled upon is called [The knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).

Comment: If you post code you've tried we might be able to help!

Answer (score 0):

If you can copy/paste your assignment /interview question without any context, then I can do the same with a web solution...

```
/* Returns true if the there is a subarray of arr[] with sum equal to 'sum'
   otherwise returns false.  Also, prints the result */
int subArraySum(int arr[], int n, int sum)
{
    int curr_sum, i, j;

    // Pick a starting point
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        curr_sum = arr[i];

        // try all subarrays starting with 'i'
        for (j = i+1; j <= n; j++)
        {
            if (curr_sum == sum)
            {
                printf ("Sum found between indexes %d and %d", i, j-1);
                return 1;
            }
            if (curr_sum > sum || j == n)
                break;
           curr_sum = curr_sum + arr[j];
        }
    }

    printf("No subarray found");
    return 0;
}
```

source: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-subarray-with-given-sum/

PS.: I dont have enough points to comment.